# core-ui-select not working after rewriting URL

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I'm using jquery plugin "core-ui-select" to stylize my form select element.
http://jquery-plugins.net/jquery-coreuiselect-stylize-select-element-with-jquery-and-css

It is working perfectly with this URL:
https://www.ni-dieu-ni-maitre.com/tshirt.php?t=t-shirt-A5770759

But once i use htaccess to rewrite the URL, it doesn't work anymore:
https://www.ni-dieu-ni-maitre.com/A-5770759/t-shirt/

Any clue where the problem comes from ? I've looked around but couldn't figure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using relative URLs in your AJAX calls:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "post",
    url: "tshirt_ajax.php?checkshop=266497&checkproducttype=210&stockcolor=" + $('#productColor5770759').val() + "&currentsize=" + currentsize,
    success: function(data){
        $('select#size').html(data);
        $('#size').coreUISelect();
        $('#quantity').coreUISelect();
    }
});
```

When the page URL is `/tshirt.php`, the AJAX URL goes to `/tshirt_ajax.php`. But when the page URL is `/A-5770759/t-shirt/` it goes to `/A-5770759/t-shirt/tshirt_ajax.php`, which doesn't work. Since the AJAX call fails, it never goes into the `success:` function, so it never calls `coreUISelect()`.

If you go into the Javascript console on the failing page, you should see this error message:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) 
    https://www.ni-dieu-ni-maitre.com/A-5770759/t-shirt/tshirt_ajax.php?checkshop=266497&checkproducttype=210&stockcolor=2&currentsize=3
```

Change the URL to:

```
    url: "/tshirt_ajax.php?checkshop=266497&checkproducttype=210&stockcolor=" + $('#productColor5770759').val() + "&currentsize=" + currentsize,
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a path problem in your ajax as a result of the extra directory in url path. Since the request fails, the plugin never gets initialized since `success` callback never fires

You have realtive url :

```
$.ajax({
    url: "tshirt_ajax.php?...
    .....
});
```

If you change it to absolute url will work

```
url: "//www.ni-dieu-ni-maitre.comt/shirt_ajax.php?..."
```

If you look in newtork tab of browser console will see the 404 ( not found) for the request

Comment: You're missing a slash after `.com`. You don't need to put the hostname in the URL, you can just use an absolute path name.